# consuming the messages from queue and then writing those messages in a text file

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have written below spring integration program in which i am trying to read messages from queue and then store the messages in a file in c: drive of my computer as if the file is not created then it will create a new file whose name will be outputmessages.txt but rite now the file is not prepared , can you please advise what went wrong how can i overcome from this..

```
 <int:channel id="output"  > 

  </int:channel>

<bean id="tibcoEMSJndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
<property name="environment">
<props>
<prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory</prop>
<prop key="java.naming.provider.url">tcp://abc.net:2333</prop>
<prop key="java.naming.security.principal">wert</prop>
<prop key="java.naming.security.credentials">wert</prop>
</props>
</property>
</bean>

    <bean id="tibcoEMSConnFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiTemplate">
            <ref bean="tibcoEMSJndiTemplate" />
        </property>
        <property name="jndiName">
            <value>GenericConnectionFactory</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

 <bean id="tibcosendJMSTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory">
            <ref local="tibcoEMSConnFactory" />
        </property>
        <property name="defaultDestinationName">
            <value>abc.test.data</value>
        </property>         
        <property name="pubSubDomain">
            <value>false</value> 
        </property>
        <property name ="receiveTimeout">
            <value>120000</value>
        </property> 
    </bean>    


    <int:channel id="input">

</int:channel>

<jms:outbound-channel-adapter channel="input" destination-name="abc.test.data"  connection-factory="tibcoEMSConnFactory" /> 

<jms:message-driven-channel-adapter channel="filesIn"   concurrent-consumers="2"  destination-name="abc.test.data" connection-factory="tibcoEMSConnFactory"   /> 

  <file:outbound-channel-adapter id="filesIn" auto-create-directory="true" filename-generator-expression="'messagesoutput.txt'"   
        directory="c:\\message\\" > 
     </file:outbound-channel-adapter>

</beans>
```

Comment: You don't have a consumer on channel `output`. Simply remove `output` and use `input` - the message-driven adapter will send its message to the outbound adapters (jms and file - if you add `input` as the channel on the file adapter).

Comment: @Gary Russell Thanks for your suggestion , but rite now my concern is to store the messages in the test file in s directory in C:L  drive of my computer can you please correct the above xml and advise for that what necassary changes i need to achieve the same please

Answer (score 0):

I see the first issue in your config:

> directory="c:\messagesoutput.txt"

it really must be a **directory** not a file path.

Another concern. It isn't clear if you want to create a file for each message or just add them all to the same.

For the last case use `mode="APPEND"`.

For the `fileName` you can use `filename-generator-expression="'messagesoutput.txt'"`.

And, please, don't mix different versions of Spring Integration jars. And try to use `versionless` `schemaLocation`.

Comment: well i agree well i want the file to be stored inside c: drive in a directory named inputmessage and i want lets say if this directory is not created in C: drive initially hen it should be created and if it is created then every time when my application runs then this directory should be emptied first , and i want there should be a single file which contain all the messages detail so in other words there will be only a single text file containing all the text messages of a queue , request you to please do the necessary corrections in my above xml itself to achieve this thing pls

Comment: You have to delete that directory on start up of your application, e.g. using `<int-event:inbound-channel-adapter event-types="org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent">` and add `auto-create-directory="true"` for your `<file:outbound-channel-adapter>`. Note: we aren't intended to do work for you. Please, read more docs and dig in the samples.

Comment: I have changed the configuration as suggested now I can see the directory created but the message from the file is not written in text file in other words the file is not created inside the message folder at all

Comment: Does not make sense. Please, share the StackTrace with exception, if any.

Comment: I have updated my xml as i can see upon execution inside c: drive in my local folder named message is created but inside message folder there is no text file named messagesoutput.txt is there as i wish file messagesoutput.txt to be created inside which all queue messages are there please advise what is wrong in my above updated xml

Comment: Which type is your `payload` from that JMS queue? `FileWritingMessageHandler` supports only: `File`, `byte[]` and `String`. Otherwise there will be an exception, which maybe hidden for you, if you have done some specific logging configuration. You can try to send to that `filesIn` some simple message with some fake text manually.